# Can we do both DML and DDL operations on a partitioned table in Oracle at the same time?

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to add partition at the same time, I need to drop an another partitions. These processes should happen in parallel. When I try this, I'm getting "Object no longer exists error". How can we handle this? I can't use GTT as we have less temp space.

Comment: I don't think you can. DML command is different from DDL command. DDL automatically commits (before and after its execution). Could you post test case which shows what you're trying to do? Seeing actual statements might illustrate the problem better than current description.

Comment: if you're trying to insert data in a dropped partition, you'll get an error.

Comment: Thank you! I was actually trying to insert data into a  dropped partition. Hence It gave me "Object no longer exists" error. Also, I'm able to do both DML and DDL at the same time in a partitioned table.